# Prove that if A is a subset of B intersect C, then A is a subset of B and C. Show why this doesn't work for union.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I try to prove that if $A \subset B \cap C$, then $A \subset B$ and $A \subset C$.
I go through:

(1) For all $x \in A, x \in B \cap C$.

(2) For all $x \in A, x \in B$ and $x \in C$

(3) For all $x \in A, x \in B$ and for all $x \in A, x \in C$

(4) So $A \subset B$ and $A \subset C$

I'm not sure if step 2 to 3 is sound. But my real question is why I can't replace all "$\cap$"s with "$\cup$"s and all "and"s with "or"s and prove the obviously false $A \subset B \cup C \implies A \subset B$ or $A \subset C$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A \subseteq B \cap C$, and take an arbitrary element $x \in A$. Since $A \subseteq B \cap C$, you know that $x \in B \cap C$, so that $x \in B$ and $x \in C$. As such, from the hypothesis that $A \subseteq B \cap C$, from the sole knowledge that $x \in A$, you can deduce that $x \in B$ (and hence $A \subseteq B$) and $x \in C$ (and hence $A \subseteq C$).

However, suppose now that $A \subseteq B \cup C$. If you wanted to prove that $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteq C$, you'd need every element of $A$ to be an element of $B$, or you'd need every element of $A$ to be an element of $C$. But given the hypothesis, you know that for each $x \in A$, either $x \in B$ or $x \in C$, but you don't know *which*—it's possible for some elements of $A$ to be in $B$, and some elements of $A$ to be in $C$, without necessitating that each element of $A$ be in only one of the sets $B$ or $C$. So the argument doesn't carry over.

And, indeed, there are counterexamples; take $A = \{ 0, 1 \}$, $B = \{ 0 \}$ and $C = \{ 1 \}$. Then $A \subseteq B \cup C$, but $A \nsubseteq B$ and $A \nsubseteq C$.

The crux of why you can't just replace $\cap$ by $\cup$ has to do with a duality in propositional logic: if $p \to (q \wedge r)$, then $p \to q$ and $p \to r$; but $p \to (q \vee r)$ does not imply $p \to q$ and it does not imply $p \to r$.

Comment: I guess that helps. Maybe could someone really symbolically flesh out why, in the union/or case, step 2 doesn't imply step 3?

Comment: @SomeNewCoderMan666: I thought my answer did flesh that out. (There's even a counterexample!) Another way of thinking about this is to ask yourself: why should it be true for unions instead of intersections? In mathematical arguments, it's almost never the case that a proof remains true if you replace one symbol by another. (For example, $x+3=3+x$ does not imply $x-3=3-x$.)

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is sound.  What fails in the case of union is the passage from $1$ to $2$.  In $2$ you would get $x \in B$ or $x \in C$.  You could have some of $A$ in $B$ and the rest of $A$ in $C$, so you can't reach step $4$.  An example is $A=\{1,2\}$, $B$ is the even numbers and $C$ is the odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   You can also express it thusly:

$$\begin{array}{l:l}(0) & A\subseteq (B\cap C) \\ (1) &\forall x~(x \in A \to x \in B \cap C)\\(2) &\forall x~(x \in A \to (x \in B\wedge x \in C))\\(2.5) &\forall x~((x \in A \to x \in B)\wedge (x \in A\to x \in C))\\(3) &\forall x~(x \in A \to x \in B)~\wedge~\forall x~(x \in A\to x \in C)\\(4) & \text{So $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$}\end{array}$$

For union, we start the same:

$$\begin{array}{l:l}(1) &\forall x~(x \in A \to x \in B \cup C)\\(2) &\forall x~(x \in A \to (x \in B\vee x \in C))\\(2.5) &\forall x~((x \in A \to x \in B)\vee (x \in A\to x \in C))\end{array}$$

But we cannot go any further because $\forall x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))$ does not infer that $(\forall x~P(x))\vee( \forall x~Q(x))$.

("All royal women are princesses or queens" does not infer that "All royal women are princesses, or all royal women are queens".)

Comment: Thanks a lot! this makes a lot of sense. Could someone prove why the second to last statement (the propositional statement) is true?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why (symbolically) distributing the universal quantifier doesn't work. (I get that it doesn't, I just don't know why formally.) Also, why does it distribute in the intersection/and case?

Comment: If everything is both $P$ and $Q$, then both everything is $P$, *and* everything is $Q$.

Comment: If everything is either $P$ or $Q$, then ... there *may* be some things which are $P$ but not $Q$, and some which are $Q$ but not $P$.

Comment: I know. It makes sense. Is there a symbolic proof of why this works but the union/or case doesn't work? Perhaps using truth tables?

Comment: I suppose my issue is with distributing universal quantifiers. Could someone give me a resource so I could see this?

Comment: So is it true to state $\forall x~(P(x)\vee Q(x))$ does not infer that $(\forall x~P(x))\vee( \forall x~Q(x))$ while $\forall x~(P(x)\land Q(x))$ does indeed infer that $(\forall x~P(x))\land( \forall x~Q(x))$?

Answer (score 0):

If you would try the same proof for unions, you get the following:

Choose $x\in A$. Since $A\subset B\cup C$ we have $x\in B\cup C$. Hence $x\in B$ or $x\in C$. Hence we get the statement:

$$\forall x\in A: (x\in B \text{ or } x\in C).$$
This is **not** equivalent to $$\forall x\in A: x\in B \text{ or } \forall x\in A:x\in C.$$
Thus this step doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can someone show why this is not equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: The best way to see this is to reformulate the statements in propositional logic and make their truth tables. Comparing the two will show they are different. (See the last three sentences of Clive's answer).

Comment: Take for example $B = {1,2,3,4} $ , $C={2,3,5,6}$ and $A={1,2,3,6}$ then see for all $x$ in $A$ , either $x$ is in $B$ or in $C$ , i.e to say that for all $x$ in $A$ : $x$ is in $B$ or $x$ is in $C$ is not true. $B $ contains elements which is not in $A$ .

Comment: But isn't p implies (q or r) equivalent to (p implies q) or (p implies r)?

Comment: For any $x$ you have statements $P(x), Q(x) $ and $R(x)$. Don't forget the quantors.